# Typescript - callback with generic prop type

Tags: typescript

I have code like below,`myFunc` requires `callback` which needed `generic` parameter.

It looks like I can pass function which not required any parameters and not getting any error notification, any idea why?

```
const myFunc = <T>(callback: (par: T) => void) => {
  const param = ('test' as any) as T;
  callback(param);
};

const callback = (par: number) => {
  console.log(par);
};

myFunc<string>(callback); // Not working as suspected - OK
myFunc<string>(() => {}); // Why I do not getting any error notification here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly described in handbook. [Comparing two functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions):

> ```
> let x = (a: number) => 0;
> let y = (b: number, s: string) => 0;
>
> y = x; // OK
> x = y; // Error
> ```
>
> You may be wondering why we allow ‘discarding’ parameters like in the example y = x. The reason for this assignment to be allowed is that ignoring extra function parameters is actually quite common in JavaScript. For example, Array#forEach provides three parameters to the callback function: the array element, its index, and the containing array. Nevertheless, it’s very useful to provide a callback that only uses the first parameter

See also relevant section of TypeScript FAQ: [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)